# How to set columns headers when export to excel?

Tags: python, pandas

I trying to change the headers titles:

```
columns = {}
for item in df.columns.map(lambda x: {x: self._get_column_header(x)}):
    columns.update(item)
self._set_column_style(df).to_excel(xls_writer,
                                    sheet_name=tab_config['tab_title'],
                                    startcol=1,
                                    startrow=4,
                                    index=False,
                                    header=False,
                                    columns=columns)
```

But this is not work.
I have to change the header only on export to excel, because `_set_column_style` function using original headers.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html):

> **header : *bool or list of str, default True***
> Write out the column names. If a list of string is given it is assumed to be aliases for the column names.

You should put your desired headers as a list of modified column names.

> **columns : *sequence or list of str, optional***
>
> Columns to write.

Here, you put the original dataframe column names in the same order, as it specifies which columns to pick from the original dataframe.